# Finding Equation Solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra

We need to determine values of k for which these have zero, one and infinite solutions.
$$x-2y=1,x-y+kz=-2,ky+4z=6$$
Now what I did:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-2&0\\1&-1&k\\0&k&4\end{pmatrix}$$ and $|A|=4-k^2$. When it has zero solution or when it is inconsistent we have $k^2=4\implies k=\pm 2$

When it is consistent or has one or infinite solutions then $|A|\ne0\implies k\ne\pm2$. How to differentiate between one and infinite solutions case of k.

I have also made rref:
$$M\sim\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&-2&0&1\\1&-1&k&-2\\0&0&4-k^2&6+k\end{array}\right]\sim\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&-2&0&1\\0&1&k&-3\\0&0&4-k^2&6+k\end{array}\right]\sim\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&-2&0&1\\0&1&k&-3\\0&0&1&\frac{6+k}{4-k^2}\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: @MichaelGaluza why?

Comment: Oops, I didn't see that RHS is $(1, -2, 6)$. If $k\ne\pm2$, there is one solution. If $k=\pm2$, it's inconsistent system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your matrix M is not in reduced row echelon form, simply row echelon form, you need to ensure that every column element above a one is zero, also I believe there may be an arithmetic mistake somewhere. Secondly a system of linear equations, written $Ax = b$ has a single solution whenever the A may be reduced to the identity matrix by elementary row operations. This is due to the fact that if A cannot be reduced to the identity matrix by row ops, then A is not invertible. The two cases that really must be decided between are not when there is one or infinitely many solutions, but when there are no solutions or infinitely many. When you have no solutions you will find a case where you have a row of A with all zeros, but a non-zero corresponding entry in b. When you have infinitely many solutions you will have a row of all zeros in A, and the corresponding entry in b will also be zero, and you will be unable to use row ops to remove some entries from the non-zero row, leading you to have statements in more than one variable.

Comment: so when $k\ne\pm2$ then it has unique solution and when $k=\pm2$ it has no solution. So you mean it can't have infinite solutions?

Comment: @ADG Your A and your equations are inconsistent, your second equation is $x - y + kz = -2$ which differs from what you wrote in A and what you row reduced. Yes, when $k \neq \pm 2$ it has one solution

Comment: I think it is correct because i did $R_2\to R_2-R_1$

Comment: Regardless of your row reduction being correct, the matrix $A$ that you presented does not match the equations you gave.

Comment: I edited it. Can you also come in the chat room

Comment: You edited the matrix, however you did not fix your rref of it given the new entries.

Comment: it was correct try doing $R_2\to R_2-R_1, R_3\to R_3+kR_2$

Comment: I had wolframalpha perform the rref, [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+rref+{{1%2C-2%2C0%2C1}%2C{1%2C-1%2Ck%2C-2}%2C{0%2Ck%2C4%2C6}}) I don't have enough rep to chat yet

Comment: I edited question again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27229/discussion-between-benjamin-gadoua-and-adg).